# Document not defined in c9

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domdocument, referenceerror

Whenever I run my code, it gives me the following error message:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/random.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:990:3


Process exited with code: 1
```

What's wrong with my code? I've looked around the internet, and I don't see why document is not defined; it should be defined automatically with the DOM.

Here's my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTMLG</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav id="navi">
            This is a header/navbar thingy
        </nav>

        <p>Blargle.</p>
        <button id="randomButton">Mix this thing up</button>
    </div>

    <script src="random.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
#container {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
#navi {
    position: static;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #7777ff;
}
```

random.js

```
document.getElementById("randomButton").onclick = randomize();

var Elements = [
    document.getElementById("container"),
    document.getElementById("navi"),
    document.getElementById("randomButton")
];
var red = 0;
var green = 0;
var blue = 0;

function randomize() {
    console.log("Button pressed");
    red = randomValue(255);
    green = randomValue(255);
    blue = randomValue(255);
    for(var i = 0; i < Elements.length; i++) {
        //console.log("here");
        Elements.style.backgroundColor = "red";//"rgb(red, green, blue)";
        //Does not actually randomize anything yet
        //I want to get the button to at least do something before I move onto the next step
    }
}

function randomValue(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
```

EDIT: I'm doing this in c9.io , in case that's relevant.

Comment: Use `.onclick = randomize;` instead of `.onclick = randomize();`

Comment: I changed it as you suggested, but the document undefined is still a different problem.

Comment: It seems that this error is from a Node.js console, not a browser console. In Node.js you can't access to document..

Comment: Assuming that c9 uses Node.js, what do i do instead of the document?